# EhCache + JGroups give "Exception on flushing of replication queue: null"

Tags: java, replication, ehcache, jgroups

I'm trying to configure EhCache with JGroups-based replication, but I get log flooded with the following exception as soon as first element is added to the cache:

```
12061 [Replication Thread] ERROR net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator - Exception on flushing of replication queue: null. Continuing...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.listRemoteCachePeers(RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.java:335)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.flushReplicationQueue(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:299)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.replicationThreadMain(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:119)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.access$100(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:57)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator$ReplicationThread.run(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:371)
```

ehcache.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
<ehcache 
  updateCheck="true" 
  monitoring="autodetect"
  defaultTransactionTimeoutInSeconds="30" 
  dynamicConfig="true">

  <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="jgroups.xml"
  />

  <defaultCache 
    maxElementsInMemory="200"
    eternal="false"
    statistics="true"
    timeToIdleSeconds="86400"
    timeToLiveSeconds="86400"    
    overflowToDisk="false">    
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
      class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
      properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=true"
    />
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />    
  </defaultCache>

</ehcache>
```

`jgroups.xml` is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config>
    <TCP start_port="7800" />
    <TCPPING 
       timeout="3000" 
       initial_hosts="localhost[7800],localhost[7800]"
       port_range="10" 
       num_initial_members="2" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500" />
    <pbcast.NAKACK 
       use_mcast_xmit="false"
       gc_lag="100"
       retransmit_timeout="300,600,1200,2400,4800"
       discard_delivered_msgs="true" />
    <pbcast.STABLE
       stability_delay="1000"
       desired_avg_gossip="50000"
       max_bytes="400000" />
    <pbcast.GMS
       print_local_addr="true"
       join_timeout="5000"
       shun="false"
       view_bundling="true" />
</config>
```

Using jgroups version 2.8.1.GA, ehcache-core version 2.5.1, ehcache-jgroupsreplication version 1.5.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: When I change to `replicateAsynchronously=false` I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.listRemoteCachePeers(RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.java:335)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.replicatePutNotification(RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.java:145)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.notifyElementPut(RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.java:132)
    at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.notifyListener(RegisteredEventListeners.java:294)
    at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.invokeListener(RegisteredEventListeners.java:284)
    at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.internalNotifyElementPut(RegisteredEventListeners.java:144)
    at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.notifyElementPut(RegisteredEventListeners.java:122)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.notifyPutInternalListeners(Cache.java:1515)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1490)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1417)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1382)
```

**UPDATE 2**: Issue is created in Terracota's JIRA: https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-927

Comment: The workaround is to either set minimum heap size to the maximum heap size to force heap allocation at start up, or put up with a few lost messages while the heap grows. http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/distribution/RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.html

Comment: set to -Xmx500M -Xms500M, but still have the same problem :(

Comment: It seems that the replication queue is not initialized at all in either case. `localhost[7800],localhost[7800]` Is this ok? http://ehcache.org/documentation/replication/jgroups-replicated-caching

Comment: (currently Ehcache JGroups replication does not work with the latest JGroups 2.8.0 library version but with the previous 2.4.7 version). http://balamaci.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/cachingpart3/

Comment: Thanks for the links. Why don't you put all your comments as an answer? They are wroth upvoting at least.

Comment: Tried 2.4.7 and localhost[7801],localhost[7802], but still with the same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Chris in [EHC927](http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-927) I was using wrong cacheEventListenerFactory class. It should be `net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory` instead of `net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory`.

Comment: It is so obvious :) This post can be used to help others to solve the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the source code for RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator class

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.1.0/ehcache-core-2.1.0-sources.jar!/net/sf/ehcache/distribution/RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java?format=ok

There is something not right when `flushReplicationQueue()` is called; it should also check for `replicationQueue != null`, not just `replicationQueue.size() == 0`. Just like what it does to test the thread's `alive()` in the while loop...

It cannot flush an object if the object does not exist or is not initialized...how can it know the object is empty or not if it does not even exist or is not initialized? Simply catching `NullPointerException` is not a nice way tell the user about it!

```
/**
 * RemoteDebugger method for the replicationQueue thread.
 * <p/>
 * Note that the replicationQueue thread locks the cache for the entire time it is writing elements to the disk.
 */
private void replicationThreadMain() {
    while (true) {
        // Wait for elements in the replicationQueue
        while (alive() && replicationQueue != null && replicationQueue.size() == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(asynchronousReplicationInterval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.debug("Spool Thread interrupted.");
                return;
            }
        }
        if (notAlive()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (replicationQueue.size() != 0) {
                flushReplicationQueue();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOG.error("Exception on flushing of replication queue: " + e.getMessage() + ". Continuing...", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The intent of the code simply to avoid CPU idle time to jump to 50% when the thread does nothing in the while loop which it may lead the user to believe something is not right with Encache if the CPU usage evolves around 50% all the time...

Probably, you need to add the property `asynchronousReplicationInterval` with a small value (100 ms to 150 ms) so that replication queue can be built. Append it as follows:

```
properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, 
replicatePuts=true, 
replicateUpdates=true, 
replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, 
replicateRemovals=true, 
asynchronousReplicationInterval=100"
```

It may be needed in the RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator constructor below:

```
/**
 * Constructor for internal and subclass use
 */
public RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator(
        boolean replicatePuts,
        boolean replicatePutsViaCopy,
        boolean replicateUpdates,
        boolean replicateUpdatesViaCopy,
        boolean replicateRemovals,
        int asynchronousReplicationInterval) {
    super(replicatePuts,
            replicatePutsViaCopy,
            replicateUpdates,
            replicateUpdatesViaCopy,
            replicateRemovals);
    this.asynchronousReplicationInterval = asynchronousReplicationInterval;
    status = Status.STATUS_ALIVE;
    replicationThread.start();
}
```

Maybe, you can just ignore the problem for the time being and let someone else report the bug if it is even considered a bug...I wonder why it says "Continuing..." later...

Comment: The problem is that exception is flooding the logs like crazy. For now I turned to simple RMI replication instead of jgroups.

Comment: But I will try your suggestion with asynchronousReplicationInterval

Comment: Still does not work with asynchronousReplicationInterval=100 :(

Comment: Anyway, I made it working with simple RMI replication (i.e. not based on JGroups)

Comment: Also create an issue in Terracota JIRA: https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-927

Comment: It appears I use wrong event listener as pointed out by Chris in jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-927